# Finding the mean for cells, which satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have cells in format 'aa-bb-cccccccc/yyyy/xx@ddddddddd.ee', where xx are the captions in format (A0-Z9) and yyyy are the numbers in format (0001-9999). We want to find the mean of yyyy for cells, which have xx='X1'. The table is huge, so iterating over each cell seems problematic. Can I use here somehow function filter(like='X1'), I have troubles finding a way to extract yyyy where this condition is satisfied.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dane.csv", sep=';')
shape = list(df.shape)
for i in range(0,shape[1]):
    if df.iloc[:,i].filter(like='X1')
```

Example of input, the first row are column names.

```
1: Brandenburg (Post-Panamax)               2: Acheron (Feeder)                        
ES-NL-10633096/1938/X1@hkzydbezon.dk/6749   DE-JP-20438082/2066/A2@qwinfhcaer.cu/68849
BE-BR-61613986/3551/B1@oqk.bf/39927         NL-LK-02275406/2136/A1@ozmmfdpfts.de/73198
PH-SA-39552610/2436/A1@venagi.hr/80578
PA-AE-59814691/4881/X1@zhicvzvksl.cl/25247  OM-PH-31303222/3671/Z1@jtqy.ml/52408
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to compute **one** mean value, for **all** cells
meeting the criterion, regardless of the column where it is.

Start from *import re*.

Then compile the regex:

```
pat = re.compile(r'(?:[A-Z]{2}-){2}\d+/(?P<n>\d+)/X1@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]{2}',
    flags=re.I)
```

And the result can be computed with the following one-liner:

```
pd.Series(df.values.reshape(-1, 1).squeeze()).str.extract(pat)\
    .dropna().astype(int).n.mean()
```

For your sample data the result is *3409.5*.

To get acquainted with the way the computation is done, execute each step
as a separate instruction and watch the results.